# VBA Range select error

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I would like to select a specific range in a worksheet, from a different worksheet like that:

```
Set sourceBook = ActiveWorkbook    
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets("test")    
Set rng = sourceSheet.Range(Cells(4, 9 ), Cells(651, 9))
```

The problem occurs at the last line, when I run the macro and get to the Set rng line, it's geneare that error:

[image]

The problem is solved, when I run the macro from the "test" sheet, but If not the "test" sheet active it's just crash like that.

Any opinion what's the problem?

Maybe another way to select range from the sheet?

Comment: Set Rng = sourceSheet.Range(Cells(4, 9).Address, Cells(651, 9).Address)

Comment: @99moorem-the problem is the `cell`'s need to be qualified,`sourceSheet.Range(sourceSheet.Cells(4, 9 ), sourceSheet.Cells(651, 9))`